# Android AVD not starting

Tags: android-emulator

I try to set up my first Android AVD by starting it from Eclipse via Android AVD Manager.
Now I created a device named "EclipeTestDevice" with the following parameters:
- Device: Nexus 4
- Target: Android 2.3.3
- CPU: Intel Atom (x86) > of course I installed the "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator" with the Android SDK-Manager
- Skin: HVGA
- Memory Options: RAM 1907, VM Heap 64 (this was a proposal by the device)

When I start the Device the new window appears, but only the text "android" (the android logo) is displayed and the device does not continue (I waited for about 10 mins).

I also tried other devices, but no one works.

Does anyone have a hint for me?

Thanks!

Comment: reduce the RAM to a lower value like 512MB and try. 1907 is very high and that is why the Emulator stalls.

Comment: Hi,

thanks for your answer!
Sorry, but editing the ram size doesn't help...
Do you have an other tip?

Or could you maybe propose the settings for an avd?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the configuration as shown in the figure(please use device and ABI of your choice). [image]